# htaccess 301 redirect adds local directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So, here is the issue:

This address: `website.com/test/test.html/`

becomes: `website.com/www/test/test.html`

I need it to be: `website.com/test/test.html`

The local directory that the site is location in is: /www/test

In my htaccess file I have:
`RewriteRule ^(.+)\/$ $1 [R=301,L]` (if there is a slash at the end of the url then redirect it without the slash)

It redirects and removes the slash great except after the .com it adds the local path (www)

Keep in mind, in my RewriteRule I cannot specify the actually address as it is dynamic so it must be $1 not website.com/test/$1

How can I get this to work without it adding the local directory "www"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this rule for trailing slash removal:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ %{ENV:BASE}$1 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. This is basically the rule I am already using except you did a permeant redirect instead of temp and you added the no escape. But, the same problem still occurs.

Comment: this is the only rule. I have google chrome set to disable cache.

Comment: Any reason why its adding my local directory to it? "www"

Comment: Nope. that was one of my original requirements: Keep in mind, in my RewriteRule I cannot specify the actually address as it is dynamic so it must be $1 not website.com/test/$1

Comment: And where do do you see `website.com/test/$1` in my rules? Can you clarify why you want to avoid `/$1` as I suggested.

Comment: because the url is usually not using the main parent url it is usually after a subdirectory

Comment: your new rule would do this: website.com/test.html instead of website.com/test/test.html

Answer (score 0):

From the Apache documentation on RewriteRule:

> In Directory and htaccess context, the Pattern will initially be
>   matched against the filesystem path, after removing the prefix that
>   led the server to the current RewriteRule (e.g. "app1/index.html" or
>   "index.html" depending on where the directives are defined).

So my first guess is that you don't have a RewriteCond defined before the RewriteRule to match to the URL information rather than the path information.

You can check out http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond for more info on RewriteCond. Off the top of my head, I'm guessing you will want to do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)\/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\/$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

If this doesn't work, you can try changing your RewriteRule to compensate for the fact that /www/ is in your path. Something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^\/www\/(.+)\/$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Hope this helps. Regex and rewrite can be a pain.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of them worked. The first one added www in just like it was originally doing. The second one didnt seem to work at all as it functioned as if I had no trailing slash condition and didnt load any of the css files.